# Неправильная верстка на мобильный телефон

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Верстал по видео. У него получилось, а у меня нет. Объясняю суть. На мобильной версии блок `container` должен стать на ширину экрана. И `col-4` соответственно. Но почему-то он выходит за рамки экрана.

В чём проблема?

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Font;
  src: url(fonts/AA-Higherup.ttf);
}

.maintext {
  font-size: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  font-family: Font;
}

.text {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: Font;
}

.arrow {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 50%;
}

.title {
  font-family: Font;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%
}

.header {
  background: red;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/lMCRt5S.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 75px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col-4 {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

.portfoliotext {
  font-family: Font;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.portfolioimg {
  text-align: center;
}

.text1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Font;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.links {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.links:hover {
  color: black;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: #450f55;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
}

@media (max-width: 1160px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-4 {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio">
  <div class="container" id="scroll">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="portfolioimg"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bkpKc0u.jpg" alt="Сайт-портфолио"></div>
        <div class="portfoliotext">Сайт на котором вы находитесь</div>
      </div>
      <!--- --->
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="portfolioimg1"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/2coBS2k.jpg" alt="Журнал о программировании"></div>
        <div class="portfoliotext">Сайт в разработке</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!----- BOTTOM ----->
<div class="bottom">
  <div class="container" id="scroll">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="text2">
          <p class="text1">Связь со мной</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--- --->
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="links">
          <center><a href="https://www.instagram.com/midykmarko/" class="links"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
            <a href="https://vk.com/midykmarko" class="links"><i class="fa fa-vk"></i></a></center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: На каком разрешении и какой контаинер?

Answer (score 2):

Первое на что советую посмотреть - адаптивность изображений.

Второе - не вижу адаптивности под малые экраны, соответственно, на них все и будет уезжать, ибо блоки стоят в ряд.

Можно сделать то, что вы хотите иным способом:
Контейнеру задать классы:

```
<div class="container d-flex flex-column flex-md-row"></div>
```

В итоге получится, что на моб. устройствах Ваши блоки будут строиться в колонну.
Далее для ваших блоков вместо .col-4 можно воспользоваться след. структурой:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-4"></div>
```

Соответственно ваш блок на моб. устройстве будет занимать всю ширину контейнера, а на >768px займет столько, сколько вам нужно. Но стоит учесть, что необходимо переписать свойства для .col-md-4